# onOptionsItemSelected ActionBarActivity doesn't respect false return

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I have some code that looks like this in an `ActionBarActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            if (isNameNull()) {
                namePicker.setError(getString(R.string.warning_name_should_not_be_empty));
                Log.d(TAG, "child name is empty");
                return false;
            }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This code is just supposed to display an error in the EditText. It worked fine when I was using `FragmentActivty`. But when I switched to `ActionBarActivity` with ToolBar this code displays the error and navigates back to parent activity. This could be a bug in `ActionBarActivity`. Any workarounds? Overriding `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` doesn't work because it was made final in `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: So what does `isNameNull()` do?

Comment: getting Log.d(TAG, "child name is empty"); in logcat???

Comment: @ianhanniballake check if the edittext have any contents

Comment: @ArnavM yes, even that error is displayed for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ActionBarActivity`, you can override [onSupportNavigateUp()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#onSupportNavigateUp()) to do custom behavior when the Up button is pressed, rather than handling it in `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
  if (isNameNull()) {
     namePicker.setError(getString(R.string.warning_name_should_not_be_empty));
     Log.d(TAG, "child name is empty");
     return false;
  }
  return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Per the Javadoc on the return value of that method:

> returns `true` if Up navigation completed successfully and this Activity was finished, `false` otherwise.